# Bitlocker & Hardware encryption on Samsung EVO 850

Tags: windows-10, ssd, encryption, bitlocker, self-encrypting-drive

I have SSD of Samsung 850 EVO, it support hardware encryption.

On SSD drive I have multiple partition, one for SYSTEM (C:)  and one for DATA (D:).

I want use hardware encoding with bitlocker for both partition. Actually i'm set bitlocker only for system. Hardware encryption for System is ok where *manage-bde -status*.

For second partition on same drive hardware encryption is not supported. Why? If try set bitlocker for DATA partition, so system use software encryption, not hardware.  If I run command in cmd

```
manage-bde -on D: -fet Hardware
```

I get error code 0x803100b2 -  The drive specified does not support hardware-based encryption.

My Notebook is Lenovo Thinkpad e550.

Its possible some fix it for use hardware encryption on multiple partion on same drive? I can format full drive again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple in the end:

You must create small empty partition before second partition, with size 100 or 200 MB (200 MB is recommended for Bitlocker.)

[Computer management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bkra.png)

After creation of empty partition bitlocker allow encrypt DATA partition with hardware method.
[manage-bde -status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5sBA.png)